# Is it possible php to include a Bootstrap navbar on each page, but using extra code to make the code display which page was active

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I'm fairly sure it is, but it is beyond my capabilities at this stage. As the title says I would like to include navbar as php for each page, to avoid repeating code, but need to modify it on each page to denote which is active.

I've got the following navbar code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light" style="background-color: #68B3E2;">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="header_logo" src="images/logo.png" width="120" height="120" alt="..."></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/index.html">Home</a>
          </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/editing.html">Editing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/reamping.html">Reamping</a>
          </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/mixing.html">Mixing <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/mastering.html">Mastering</a>
          </li>

        </ul>


          <a class="right_btn btn-primary btn-lg"  href="/buypage.html" role="button">BUY NOW</a>

      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navbar code should be in a header, where you would write the HTML code once, and include the header in all of your pages.

You can then check with PHP if the page URL you are on matches the href from each of the menu items, and if true add a `class='active'` for example.

You can also do the same with JS, not utilizing PHP.

Comment: Thanks. I'm presuming the header should be included as a PHP file. Is that right?

Comment: Hey Ron. I've got the php include function working, but am really stuggling to check if the url matches the href from the menu items, and add a class='active'.

Would you be able to elaborate?

Comment: If you are using a PHP framework there should be a function to show you the `route` or `slug` f the page you are on. If you are using plain PHP, you can try to match the current page you are on with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`

Comment: Thanks so much, I've managed to get it working using the following:
`code

<?php 

$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if($currentpage=="/index.php") 
    
                {echo '<li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/index.php">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>';
                 
                } else {
    
                echo '<li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/index.php">Home</a></li>';
                }

?> ` It does seem rather convoluted. Is there are more elgant approach?

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution I believe than Ron's is using pure CSS. Each page can have it's unique ID/Class (eg. .mixing-page) and select the menu based on that.

```css
.mixing-page .navbar li:nth-child(4) a {
 color :red;
}
```

```html
<div class="mixing-page">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light" >
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/editing.html">Editing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/reamping.html">Reamping</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/mixing.html">Mixing <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/mastering.html">Mastering</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>
```